# Android integrate app with default alarm clock

Tags: android, android-alarms

I wish to : record the time at which the user presses the `STOP` button in their default android alarm clock.

I've read that Android apps are sandboxed so data from one app can't be used in another. Hence the doubt.

Please tell me if the above can be done and how (general direction is sufficient).

Answer (score 1):

There are thousands of Android device models. These will have hundreds of alarm clock apps pre-installed, and the user can install other alarm clock apps from app distribution channels.

None of these apps have to tell third-party apps when the user presses "stop". Furthermore, there is no standard `Intent` action for "the user pressed 'stop'", so even if some alarm clock apps do broadcast an `Intent` or something, there is no requirement that they all broadcast the *same* `Intent` structure.

Comment: Bummer. I was really hoping there was a broadcast receiver for listening to alarm rings and response.